# Are there any libraries for UILabel animations for Games?

Tags: ios, animation, uilabel

I'd like to have some sort of a method that would take a point and text, and display a UILabel and have it flow upwards until it completely fades out. I see this in a lot of games and would like to have it in mine. Are there any libraries for this, or do I need to write my own classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just writing my own Class, you can find it on Git here:
https://github.com/theMonster/Game-Label-Animations.git

Answer (score 0):

I came across one library in cocoa controls, it includes some basic but cool animations. [Here is the link for source code.](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/BBCyclingLabel)

Comment: Useful, but not what I needed. Thanks though.